# Kmscube on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: opengl, mesa, drm

I am trying to run kmscube on Ubuntu 16.04. 
I have built it with `meson` and `ninja`, but I see this error when I am trying to run it:

```
i965_dri.so does not support the 0xffffffff PCI ID.
Using display 0x287e0f0 with EGL version 1.4
...
Using modifier ffffffffffffff
Modifiers failed!
failed to set mode: Permission denied

glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem with your graphics driver. Try to reinstall it and then build kmscube again.

Comment: From "failed to set mode: Permission denied" maybe you should run it as root or as a super user

Comment: Unfortunately, root does not help. Another OpenGL and OpenGLES demos works fine but they are using X11. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Mystery solved. I am able to run it. Thank you guys!

Comment: How did you solve it? Please post the solution as an answer and accept it, so that other people with the same problem can solve it too.

Comment: The demo was fine but in this case it must be run by using Ctrl+alt+F1 and ./ <path to demo>kmscube .